# why update after evict make the object dirty?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my application and have the following situation:

An object is queried from the database. It is edited and updated the children (just the children edited).

In the Object I have column that save the version with @Version annotation.
the version needs to updated every change after commit the Session.
but it's not updated because the object not became dirty.

I found that if I do that:

```
 session.evict(entity); 
 session.update(entity);
```

it's work the object became dirty and the version increased.

I try to change the `session.update(entity);` to `session.merge(entity);`

but it didn't work (the version didn't inc).

can somebody explain me why?

or give me another way to update the version of the object in case of changes in the children.